# Get Data for Grouping all Months in a year using MySql and DB2

Tags: mysql, db2

below is my query

```
    SELECT DISTINCT e2.status as status, e2.year as year, e2.month as month,e2.Jan,e2.Feb,e2.Mar,e2.Apr,e2.May,e2.Jun,e2.Jul,e2.Aug,e2.Sep,e2.Oct,e2.Nov, e2.Dece, e2.countTotal FROM tranx_history e1 INNER JOIN ( 

   SELECT YEAR(e.create_dt) AS year, MONTH(e.create_dt) AS month,
   SUM(CASE WHEN MONTH(e.create_dt) = 01 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS Jan,
   SUM(CASE WHEN MONTH(e.create_dt) = 02 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS Feb,
   SUM(CASE WHEN MONTH(e.create_dt) = 03 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS Mar,
   SUM(CASE WHEN MONTH(e.create_dt) = 04 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS Apr,
   SUM(CASE WHEN MONTH(e.create_dt) = 05 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS May,
   SUM(CASE WHEN MONTH(e.create_dt) = 06 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS Jun,
   SUM(CASE WHEN MONTH(e.create_dt) = 07 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS Jul,
   SUM(CASE WHEN MONTH(e.create_dt) = 08 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS Aug,
   SUM(CASE WHEN MONTH(e.create_dt) = 09 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS Sep,
   SUM(CASE WHEN MONTH(e.create_dt) = 10 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS Oct,
   SUM(CASE WHEN MONTH(e.create_dt) = 11 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS Nov,
   SUM(CASE WHEN MONTH(e.create_dt) = 12 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS Dece,
   SUM(CASE WHEN MONTH(e.create_dt) >= 01 AND MONTH(e.create_dt) <= 12 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as countTotal,
   e.trnx_status as status
   from tranx_history e
   GROUP BY  e.trnx_status, MONTH(e.create_dt),YEAR(e.create_dt) ) e2 ON YEAR(e1.create_dt)  = e2.year AND MONTH(e1.create_dt) = e2.month ORDER BY e2.year asc, e2.month asc
```

For the Above query, The Output we are getting is first it is grouping by Jan then in the next row it is grouping by Feb even though status and year are same

i want the output Jan and Feb with same status and year in a single row not in different rows

Comment: You forgot to ask a question

Comment: and to format the query, so someone cares to read it

Comment: You have added month in the group by clause so it is grouping on 3 columns. If you want to group on status and year only then remove month from group by

Comment: Thanks it is working @wonderbell